# Samba server doesn't appear to work on system restart

Tags: networking, server, samba, restart

I finally got a Samba file server setup successfully and connected to it and could transfer files fine.  I mapped it as a network drive on several windows computers.  I shut it down for the night as it is not yet in its permanent air conditioned spot (would get too hot where it was if left running).  Today, when I turned it on, when I tried to connect, it couldn't connect.

Is there something I must do server side every time I restart the system?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that Samba is running on the server? That would be the first thing to verify, you should be able to run the command:

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

to verify that Samba is actually available and running.